# explaining qubits to beginning CS students

Tags: quantum-information, education

&I have 15 minutes as a guest lecturer to explain the notion of quantum computing to CS students in a Theory of Computation class. There is a lot of information on the web, e.g., http://arstechnica.com/science/2010/01/a-tale-of-two-qubits-how-quantum-computers-work/,
but the material seems either (necessarily?) too long, or complex, or both. E.g., to use the approach in the link above would require a diversion into polarization of light. Adding to my challenge is that some (most?) of the students have studied neither linear algebra nor probability.

My instinct is that a few high level bits (pun noted) offering a comparison between qubits and digital bits in key features, indications of what's computable and not, something about parallelism, information storage and transfer, etc., may be the approach. As usual in teaching one wants people to "think" they understand.

It would be very helpful to have pointers to URLs, books, papers, etc., to help my prep for this task. Meanwhile, the large number of those who do understand the topic well (I'm not among them) may roll their eyes, thankfully not coherently enough to affect the earth's angular momentum.

Edit_1: I found this old Q/A ([Quantum Computing, Qubit Creation/Entanglement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17628/quantum-computing-qubit-creation-entanglement?rq=1)) which seems helpful. Also, my thanks to @glance for the pointer to tcs.

Comment: note that there is also a [cstheory.se] stackexchange. Given your target audience maybe you can find better answers on the subject there?

Comment: Based on your suggestion @glance I joined that list. A quick browse gave me some things to look at, more for my personal interests than my more immediate task. Maybe it's just up to me to come up with an approach. My hope was that the Physics crowd had seen requests like mine so often that they would have well worn pointers to offer.